# Typescript Is it possible to distinct generic argument void?

Tags: typescript

A function has generic type argument.

When context is void, I want to input 0 arguments, otherwise I want to input 1 argument.

If I used as `context: Context | void` in function argument, Even when I need to add context, **But I can add void type.**

is there any way to input 0 argument or check whether it is typed as void?

```
class TestClass<Context = void> {
  protected context : Context

  constructor(context: Context) {
    this.context = context;
  }
}

export function genericVoidNeedArgument<Context = void>(
  context: Context,
) {
  // can check type..?
  return new TestClass(context);
}

type UserType = {
  id: string
  // and so on..
};

// expected : o, real : error
// An argument for 'context' was not provided.
genericVoidNeedArgument();

// expected : error, real : error
genericVoidNeedArgument<UserType>();

// expected : o, real : o
genericVoidNeedArgument<UserType>({id: "123"});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Function Overloads](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) to do that.

```
class TestClass<Context = void> {
  protected context: Context;

  constructor(context: Context) {
    this.context = context;
  }
}

function genericVoidNeedArgument(): TestClass<void>;

function genericVoidNeedArgument<Context>(
  context: Context
): TestClass<Context>;

function genericVoidNeedArgument(context?: any): any {
  return new TestClass(context);
}

type UserType = {
  id: string;
};

genericVoidNeedArgument();
genericVoidNeedArgument<UserType>({id: "123"});
genericVoidNeedArgument<UserType>();
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ -> Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEAqCmEAuBhcUA8KD2A7J8AHktALzQBu2AlgCYB80A3gLABQ00ADgE7YHACtaMDwFiALmg58RJAG527TqNzIeAV0HYeAClXikUmYYCUzZZ2hIAFtQgA6A3LIixcxR2gBfdr7bsAGYauILUeNAA5vC48DzUwABqNLQAcvDwtACCPJEaALYxSLqmUgjIaJAQGFR09J5BIWER0bHxSSnpmTl5hfhY7sT0upbOktKDSOylcIio6NUmcvVKbMGhSOG4UTFxCcl0Xdm5BUX6kwD8UmC4AJ4zN7cWXjzwSBo827EA7rMVC%20dZMRTJ5-OwkLcuPBoABVCBxWCQ6HkVheOhSdTUXCRUENNitPYdQ4ZY69M4g9gE9oHNIknqnfpwhFI4ZMdHQABEAEYAEwAZg53gp%20N21M6dJOfSQGCZPERUOGIKAA)

Answer (score 0):

A different approach: overloading the constructor with dynamic `...args`

```js
type UserType = {
    id: string
    // and so on..
};

class TestClass<Context = void> {
    protected context: Context;

    constructor(...args: Context extends void ? [] : [context: Context])
    constructor(context: Context) {
        this.context = context;
    }
}

const a = new TestClass<UserType>({ id: "123" });
const b = new TestClass<UserType>(); // Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
const c = new TestClass();
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAqgzhATgFXNAvFA3gKCvqASwBMAuKOYRQgOwHM8CB6JqAQxuIoHspuaAdAJwBfANw4cAYwA2bOHCjIIlAMJyFAHlX9gEAB7AomAG7cSAPmyN8YRNz1S9XKboPByOmnsMSbUVxpKRABXJ25EAAohATZEOjhPN0ModwhORTMSKAB+KABtAF0ocnzAnw8oLwrCgEp-QOCw4AjI8vck73da6wI+qGAAC0I4AXaUzHHgCT6RUUlGozZjKBoIAHclFWB1eThNeCRUSAtIrCIyKAAiAEYAJgBmK6gRWolFqAAjFbXN5TUNPtDig0Kc3tJ+JQAj8NlsAXtIuCgA)

Pro: no need for the extra function

Contra: not that intuitive